# Не создаётся виртуальная среда

Tags: python

Для создания виртуального окружения, я создал папку, открыл в ней окно PowerShell, написал в нём

```
python -m venv venv
```

но папка `venv` не создалась. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вывод из консоли после ввода команды

Comment: Мне помогла статья `https://habr.com/ru/post/491916/`